# Adding "aggregations" to my Facebook application

Tags: facebook-graph-api, aggregation

I don't understand how to add aggregations to my application on Facebook graph.
I submited my application to Facebook and I got the answer "changes needed":

> "Note: If you are creating an aggregation based on the object, you need to add 6-7 unique sample objects, and then create a corresponding sample action acting on each of these unique objects. (You can not just create 6-7 sample actions pointing to the same sample object). Submission Checklist: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/checklist Please make changes below and resubmit for review."

What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say this documentation page is a good start.

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/define-units/